# Probability a geometric Brownian motion stays within an interval.

Tags: brownian-motion

Let $X_s$ be a $(\mu,\sigma)$ geometric Brownian motion with $X_0 = x$.  For some positive numbers $c < x < d$ and time $t$, what is the probability $X_s \in [c,d]$ for all $s \in [0,t]$?

In particular, is there a closed-form expression for this probability?  This problem is not too bad with an arithmetic Brownian motion, but I am struggling to find a clean solution for the geometric case.

Comment: Does writing $X_t=X_0\exp((\mu-\sigma^2/2)t+\sigma W_t)$ helps ?

Comment: For sure, but I'm struggling to go from that observation to a clean formula for the probability I describe in the question.